# what with -- what does that actually mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Head First Servlets and JSP, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516680.do)

Example:

> The large number of acknowledgments is because we’re testing the theory
>   that everyone mentioned in a book acknowledgment will buy at least one copy,
>   probably more, **what with relatives and everything**.

How is that part in bold connected to the rest of the sentence and what does it actually say? Specifically, I don't understand the **what with** part.

Comment: They're listing the reasons for “probably more.” See [**what with**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%20with).

Comment: I'd understand what they want to say, but is this good style?

Comment: "what with" was actually the point of confusion for me. Use that to write your answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what with relatives and everything

could also be written as:

> what with relatives and all

It means: Considering relatives and others that they know, each person being acknowledged are expected to result in sales of more than one book.
This is a common view when low sales are anticipated. Direct sales might be low, but they may talk others into buying.