# What does it mean by "what with all the arrangements for the World Cup"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire:

> “I’ve told Mr. Crouch that I’ll have it ready by Tuesday,” Percy was saying pompously. “That’s a bit sooner than he expected it, but I like to keep on top of things. I think he’ll be grateful I’ve done it in good time, I mean, **it’s extremely busy in our department just now, what with all the arrangements for the World Cup.** We’re just not getting the support we need from the Department of Magical Games and Sports. Ludo Bagman —”

In the bold sentence, does the "what" refer to "it" , meaning **all the things we have to do  or our jobs**?

And does **"with all the arrangements..."** mean **including or relating to all the arrangements...**

Comment: In this context "what with" could be replaced by "because of".

Comment: **what with** _idiom   informal_  used to talk about the reasons for a particular situation, especially a bad or difficult situation: _I'm very tired, what with travelling all day yesterday and having a disturbed night._ [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/what-with)

Comment: Compare [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88826/what-with-what-does-that-actually-mean) on "what with".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "**what with all the arrangements for the World Cup**" means "because of" or "due to."

So, Percy is saying that the department is extremely busy, and one reason for this busyness is all the arrangements they are making for the World Cup. The "**what**" here doesn't refer specifically to "it" or "our jobs"; rather, it refers to the general situation or circumstance of being busy.

And yes, "**with all the arrangements**" means "including" or "relating to" all the arrangements for the World Cup.

Comment: In other words, the _what with_ expression is a reason adjunct.

Answer (score 1):

... *it’s extremely busy in our department just now,* [*what with all the* *arrangements for the World Cup*].

The *what with* idiom is used here to introduce the bracketed reason adjunct.

The adjunct gives the reason for it being extremely busy in our department just now.